# Database design and ORM for multitenant SAAS application

Tags: azure-sql-database, multi-tenant, saas

I am designing a multi tenant SAAS enterprise cloud application.Each tenant must be able to customize the UI and workflow as per his needs.Tenant can add as many fields he wants to the UI.

We are using single db for each tenant means only one tenant data resides in a single db.As per the current design which I have planned I am gonna restrict tenant with a maximum number of fields in UI and hence I can keep table design constant(number of columns).The table will be having varchar columns and column name as Column1,Column2 etc.Tenant data will be stored in this table.The actual name of column and datatype will be stored in a mapping table.

The database is SQL Azure and ORM is entity framework.When a tenant is provisioned the database details will be stored in a master database and from there the application will be redirected to tenant specific db.I have chosen this design to keep the entity framework common as its a multi tenant application and all tenant will be having same table structure and hence no EF context needs to be regenerated dynamically.Only one dbcontext can be used to connect to all clients.I have come to this design after lots of reaseach.

Now the problem is as all fields are varchar using aggregate functions,indexing,ordering etc will have huge performance impact.

Right now we are in architecting phase and hence we do have flexibility to change the design or rather change the technologies and go to NOSQL side.

Please suggest if there are better options or this is the right way to do.

One of the few articles I have refereed is
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_tde

Answer (score 1):

To achieve multi-tenant scenarios with SQL Azure Database, you can use Elastic Database Pool to manage easily a database per-tenant. [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-design-patterns-multi-tenancy-saas-applications/) is a nice documentation to manage multi-tenant SaaS applications with SQL Azure.